# wants to allocate memory dynamically as per length of data in C program

Tags: c

here i want to run this program and take one character pointer like `char *finalstring`.

but how can i allocate memory to this `finalstring`.

i cant declare like 512 bytes and 1024 bytes etc. because here output not fix its depend on Bluetooth address.

So any one can tell me i want to store these all output data which i prints here in one character pointer. i want to concat every while loop execution and want to declare dynamic memory.

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {

    char *sdpCommand = "sdptool browse 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5";

    FILE *fp;
    char* finalstring = malloc(512);
    char result[512];
    fp = popen(sdpCommand, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n");
        return;
    }

    if (finalstring) {
        *finalstring = 0;

        /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
        while (fgets(result, sizeof(result) - 1, fp) != NULL) {
            char* newfinalstring = realloc(finalstring, strlen(result) + 1);
            if (newfinalstring) {
                finalstring = newfinalstring;
                strcat(finalstring, result);
            }
            printf("Output    :::  %s", result);
        }
        free(finalstring);
    }
    printf("\nfinal Output    :::  %s", finalstring);

    free(finalstring);
    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    sleep(1);

}
```

output :

```
   Output    :::  Browsing 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5 ...
Output    :::  Service RecHandle: 0x10000
*** glibc detected *** ./sdptool: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00011008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x400a2f3c]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x400a72ac]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0x108)[0x400a84ec]
./sdptool[0x86d4]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x120)[0x4004efd4]
======= Memory map: ========
00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 1f:04 16647      /opt/WL1271_demo_01/bluetooth_scripts/sdptool
00010000-00011000 rwxp 00000000 1f:04 16647      /opt/WL1271_demo_01/bluetooth_scripts/sdptool
00011000-00032000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001d000 r-xp 00000000 1f:04 747        /lib/ld-2.8.so
4001d000-40021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40024000-40025000 r-xp 0001c000 1f:04 747        /lib/ld-2.8.so
40025000-40026000 rwxp 0001d000 1f:04 747        /lib/ld-2.8.so
40026000-40032000 r-xp 00000000 1f:04 762        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
40032000-40039000 ---p 0000c000 1f:04 762        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
40039000-4003a000 rwxp 0000b000 1f:04 762        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
4003a000-40157000 r-xp 00000000 1f:04 753        /lib/libc-2.8.so
40157000-4015e000 ---p 0011d000 1f:04 753        /lib/libc-2.8.so
4015e000-40160000 r-xp 0011c000 1f:04 753        /lib/libc-2.8.so
40160000-40161000 rwxp 0011e000 1f:04 753        /lib/libc-2.8.so
40161000-40164000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40200000-40221000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40221000-40300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
bec5c000-bec71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

Comment: why not store an array of your results? or better yet save the output to a file!

Comment: Perhaps look up `malloc`, `strncpy` and `strncat`, if you can't use C++, and then tell us if you get stuck?

Comment: By the way, the buffer size in `fgets` doesn't need the "-1", it will read at most one less than the size given to it.

Comment: problem is not in that. Problem in realloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of how long the string is currently, and how much is allocated. Then when adding more text, if the new length will be more than what's allocated you allocate more.

Here's some code you can use:

```
/* How much memory to allocate each time */
#define BUFFER_CHUNK_LENGTH  128

struct buffer_data
{
    char  *buffer;   /* The actual buffer */
    size_t length;   /* Length of data in buffer */
    size_t alloc;    /* Bytes allocated for the buffer */
};

struct buffer_data *create_buffer()
{
    /* Use "calloc" to clear all members */
    return calloc(1, sizeof(struct buffer_data));
}

void add_to_buffer(struct buffer_data *buffer, char *text)
{
    /* Use "+1" for the string termincator character */
    if ((buffer->length + strlen(text) + 1) > buffer->alloc)
    {
        /* Is this the first allocation? */
        int is_first = (buffer->buffer == NULL);

        /* Not enough memory in buffer, reallocate to increase */
        buffer->buffer = realloc(buffer->buffer, buffer->alloc + BUFFER_CHUNK_LENGTH);
        buffer->alloc += BUFFER_CHUNK_LENGTH;

        if (is_first)
            *buffer->buffer = '\0';  /* Make sure string is terminated */

        /* Try to add again */
        add_to_buffer(buffer, text);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(buffer->buffer, text);
        buffer->length += strlen(text);
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* You stuff here... */

    struct buffer_data *buffer = create_buffer();

    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), fp) != NULL)
    {
        add_to_buffer(buffer, result);
    }

    printf("Buffered data: %s", buffer->buffer);

    /* More of your stuff here */
}
```

**PS.**
Don't forget to clean up after you, by freeing both the buffer data and the buffer structure.

### Edit

**This code doesn't contain any error checking or handling! Use of a debugger is highly recommended!**

Comment: its giving segmentation fault

Comment: Can u please See my Edited Question Someone here suggest me that code i used that one becasuse its easy and too short. so can i use that code? or your one is perfect?

Comment: Here i have to free which buffer. free(buffer) is correct ? or there is otherone?

Comment: @user1089679 You need to both `free(buffer->buffer)` and `free(buffer)`. And of course you can use the code, it's what it's here for. :)

Comment: can i take your personal id please..Are u really Great.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is `realloc()`.  `man malloc` has the skinny.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a specific number of bytes with `fgets()` and if you need to append, use `malloc()`, `memcpy()` and `free()` or `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/), [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/), and [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/):

```
char* buffer = malloc(514);
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, fp) != NULL) {
    realloc(results, sizeof(results)+sizeof(buffer));
    memcpy(results+sizeof(results, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
printf("Output    :::  %s", result);
```

Comment: Why u wrote  realloc(results, sizeof(buffer)); ? May be instead of results buffer will be used?

Comment: @user1089679: to add the size of the buffer to results, so that you later can append it

Comment: The size argument to `realloc` should be the _new_ size. Also not that `sizeof(buffer)` in your case is only the size of the _pointer_ not the allocated memory!

Comment: its given error like which i above posted in my edited question